# Coalesce and Any doesn't work together

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm trying to run command like this:

```
SELECT PITANJEID, NASLOV, ODGOVOR1, ODGOVOR2, ODGOVOR3, ODGOVOR4, ODGOVOR5, POENA, PITANJE 
FROM KVIZ_PITANJA 
WHERE KVIZ_GRUPA_ID = COALESCE(@ID, ANY(SELECT KVIZ_GRUPA_ID FROM KVIZ_PITANJA))
```

Problem here is I get error:

> Token unknown ANY

When I run command with only `Coalesce(2, 1)` it runs normally.

When I run command with only `Any(select kviz_grupa_id from kviz_pitanja)` it also works normally.

Why do I get this error when I put these two commands together?

I want to achieve if user passed `null` as parameter to not use `where` command for that parameter at all so this is approach I wanted to try.

Answer (score 4):

SOME and ANY must be preceded by a comparison operation (=, <, >, etc.), so having it embedded in a COALESCE is causing your error. It looks like you're trying to say "if there's an @ID, then just look that up, otherwise return everything." If that's the case, you can use this structure (common in SSRS applications):

```
SELECT PITANJEID, NASLOV, ODGOVOR1, ODGOVOR2, ODGOVOR3, ODGOVOR4, ODGOVOR5, POENA, PITANJE 
FROM KVIZ_PITANJA 
WHERE (KVIZ_GRUPA_ID = @ID OR @ID IS NULL)
```